# How to import functions javascript

Tags: javascript, import, package, export

i need to export my functions from index.js

And use it in app.js
like
myFunction()
Dont
var.myFunction()
And whithout using

```
{myFunction} = require("index.js")
```

Because i need import them all

Comment: Where are you going to use this, browser or node or ??? Import/Export means you want to write it off as a `module`, however you want to use it without making any import-style, and freely like `functionName()`, then you will have to have a global plugin styled definitions, but then the question is, how this gets loaded into the context of your use. It will be better if you can add some more info to your question.. Plz...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Please learn more about the CommonJS module specification.

https://flaviocopes.com/commonjs/

Let's assume we have `util.js`.

```js
exports.one = () => {}
exports.two = () => {}
exports.three = () => {}
```

Then as I know we can import everything like this.

```js
const Util = require('utils.js');

Util.one()
Util.two()
Util.three()
```

Using ES6 syntax

```js
import * as Util from 'utils.js'
```

---

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: i need without util.    i need to use one() direct

Comment: I got your point,  if you are working with NodeJS I don't think that is possible,  but in browser you can do something like window.one = () => {} .

Answer (score 0):

Assign all functions in `index.js` to module.exports

for example , below content in your index.js

`module.exports= { t: x=> console.log ('this is '+x), add: (x,y) => x+y}`

to import them use

`const myFunctions =require('index.js')`

and then you can call
`myFunctions.add(2,3)`

To learn more check module.exports in : https://learnjsx.com/category/2/posts/es6-moduleExports

Comment: I need this but without myFunctions

Comment: I need to use add() only